# Shall I use the Longstaff and Schwartz method or the forward Monte Carlo method to price an American call?

Tags: option-pricing, programming, finance-mathematics

I am comparing two methods: Least squares by Longstaff and Schwartz and A Forward Monte Carlo method. I am not sure what price I should consider as the "true value" to compare these two approaches. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. The option is an American call.

Comment: Please describe the option: it is an American Call on how many assets? What is the underlying model GBM?

Comment: hmm for an American call on a dividend paying stock, the American price is the same as the European. Unless the problem is high-dim use a tree or the BS formula.

Comment: *non-dividend paying stock. Indeed I would compare to the result obtained with a tree or finite difference scheme (if single or two assets).

Comment: Ok, so I can just use the standard Black-Scholes equation for a European option on a dividend paying stock?

Comment: I meant non-dividend paying... if it pays dividends then you need an American pricer, eg a tree

Comment: @MarkJoshi I see, the thing is that the tree is going to be less accurate then the LSM and Forward Monte Carlo method from what I understand, so I just use the Black-Scholes price on a dividend paying stock as the "true value", is that a bad idea? I just want to illustrate which method (LSM or Forward) is more accurate

Comment: the tree is much more accurate than MC methods for American options on a stock. Using the BS formula would be a very bad idea.

Comment: @MarkJoshi Ok, the tree is termed what though exactly?

Comment: @MarkJoshi Is it the Binomial Tree?

Comment: binomial tree -- there are about 30 different binomial trees. Any would do OK if you use enough steps. The Leisen-Reimer or J4 trees are good. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1030143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the optimal exercise boundary is only an estimate, both the methods underestimate the "true value" of the option.

A simple comparison would be whichever method produced higher price for the option is better.

For this comparison to make sense, you could

- re-use underlying stock simulation across both the methods.
- make sure variance of price produced is reasonably low for both.

The "better" value of the two is still a lower bound and doesn't really throw information on how big the error is.

You could implement dual method to produce upper bound and thus a range for the true option price.

Again, this range is meaningful only if the underlying stock simulation ( vol model ) is meaningful.

Remember 'garbage in garbage out'